Assume I have 2 objects & according to them I want new object
const data = {
    name : "teahyung",
    fatherName : "kim-ji-hyung",
    age : 26
}

const data1 = {
    name : "jangkook",
    fatherName : "kim-ji-hyung",
    age : 23
}

ans = {
    name : {
        old : "teahyung",
        new : "jangkook"
    },
    age : {
        old : 26,
        new : 23
    }
}


What's wrong with this approach:
const ans = {   name: { old: data.name, new: data1.name },   age: { old: data.age, new: data1.age } };

assume stack overflow isn't a code writing service where you post your coding requirements and someone writes the code for you

function compareData(data, data1) {
    const ans = {};
    for (const key in data) {
        if (data[key] !== data1[key]) {
            ans[key] = { old: data[key], new: data1[key] };
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

const data = { name: "teahyung", fatherName: "kim-ji-hyung", age: 26 };
const data1 = { name: "jangkook", fatherName: "kim-ji-hyung", age: 23 };

const ans = compareData(data, data1);
console.log(ans);

This function takes data and data1 objects and returns the differences between these two objects as an object named ans. The function checks each key in the data object and if the values in data and data1 are different, it adds the old and new values for that key to the ans object.

You should create a function that takes the original and updated objects.
This function will:

Loop over the updated keys
Check if the original has the key, and the value if different
Add a new key-value pair to the result



const
  originalData = { name : "teahyung", fatherName : "kim-ji-hyung", age : 26 },
  updatedData  = { name : "jangkook", fatherName : "kim-ji-hyung", age : 23 };

const diff = (original, updated) => {
  const result = {};
  for (let key in updated) {
    if (original.hasOwnProperty(key) && original[key] !== updated[key]) {
     result[key] = { old: original[key], new: updated[key] };
    }
  }
  return result;
};

const ans = diff(originalData, updatedData);

console.log(ans);
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }



Here is a more functional approach:


const
  originalData = { name : "teahyung", fatherName : "kim-ji-hyung", age : 26 },
  updatedData  = { name : "jangkook", fatherName : "kim-ji-hyung", age : 23 };

const diff = (original, updated) => Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(updated)
  .filter((k) => original.hasOwnProperty(k) && original[k] !== updated[k])
  .reduce((r, k) => r.set(k, { old: original[k], new: updated[k]}), new Map));

const ans = diff(originalData, updatedData);

console.log(ans);
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }



